# how to change expired time in REST framework JWT Auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, pyjwt

I read official document of REST framework JWT Auth. It provides the additional setting options for setting expired time. However, I am not sure where to insert the setting options code. Do I need create a separate setting file to hold it or just paste the setting options code in setting.py?

Link of REST framework JWT Auth:http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings

Answer (score 0):

No need of new settings file. Just add it to the django settings file